# How to find rows which differ by a given amount in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, loops, unix-timestamp

So I have a data table which looks like

[image]

Where each row has a timestamp column in Unix time. I need to find all the places where two entries with the same resource_id are x(day month, year etc) amount of time apart, so I need a query that will go through and look at the differences between one row and the next and spit back the ones which differ by more than a specified amount.

Anybody have any ideas on how to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really a nuisance when you put your sample data into a question as an image, because it makes it hard to build an example on sqlfiddle.  Also, question: are these rows supposed to be ordered by the `resource_id` column?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a cross join to compare every row in the table with every other row in the table then compare the field. For example the following will return where the two rows are 2 months apart.

```
SELECT t.resource_id, s.resource_id
FROM table t CROSS JOIN table s
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,t.timestamp,s.timestamp) = 2
```

Note that this could be extremely slow if the table is large. Or according to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) just saying JOIN without specifying the condition will result in a cartesian product which is equivalent to a cross join.